# Python currying and partial

Tags: python, partial, currying

While doing programming exercises on codewars.com, I encountered an [exercise](https://www.codewars.com/kata/53cf7e37e9876c35a60002c9/train/python) on currying and partial functions.

Being a novice in programming and new to the topic, I searched on the internet for information on the topic and got quite far into solving the exercise. However I have now stumbled upon an obstacle I can't seem to overcome and am here looking for a nudge in the right direction.

The exercise is rather simple: write a function that can curry and/or partial any input function and evaluates the input function once enough input parameters are supplied. The input function can accept any number of input parameters. Also the curry/partial function should be very flexible in how it is called, being able to handle many, many different ways of calling the function. Also, the curry/partial function is allowed to be called with more inputs than required by the input function, in that case all the excess inputs need to be ignored.

Following the exercise link, all the test cases can be found that the function needs to be able to handle.

The code I came up with is the following:

```
from functools import partial
from inspect import signature

def curry_partial(func, *initial_args):
    """ Generates a 'curried' version of a function. """

    # Process any initial arguments that where given. If the number of arguments that are given exceeds 
    # minArgs (the number of input arguments that func needs), func is evaluated

    minArgs = len(signature(func).parameters)
    if initial_args:
        if len(initial_args) >= minArgs: 
            return func(*initial_args[:minArgs])

        func = partial(func, *initial_args)
        minArgs = len(signature(func).parameters)

    
    # Do the currying
    def g(*myArgs):
        nonlocal minArgs

        # Evaluate function if we have the necessary amount of input arguments
        if minArgs is not None and minArgs <= len(myArgs):
                return func(*myArgs[:minArgs]) 
            
        def f(*args):
            nonlocal minArgs
            newArgs = myArgs + args if args else myArgs

            if minArgs is not None and minArgs <= len(newArgs):
                return func(*newArgs[:minArgs])
            else:
                return g(*newArgs)  
        return f
    return g
```

Now this code fails when the following test is executed:

```
test.assert_equals(curry_partial(curry_partial(curry_partial(add, a), b), c), sum)
```

where add = a + b + c (properly defined function), a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, and sum = 6.

The reason this fails is because `curry_partial(add, a)` returns a function handle to the function `g`. In the second call, `curry_partial(<function_handle to g>, b)`, the calculation `minArgs = len(signature(func).parameters)` doesn't work like I want it to, because it will now calculate how many input arguments function `g` requires (which is `1`: i.e. `*myArgs`), and not how many the original `func` still requires. So the question is, how can I write my code such that I can keep track of how many input arguments my original `func` still needs (reducing that number each time I am partialling the function with any given initial arguments).

I still have much to learn about programming and currying/partial, so most likely I have not chosen the most convenient approach. But I'd like to learn. The difficulty in this exercise for me is the combination of partial and curry, i.e. doing a curry loop while partialling any initial arguments that are encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out.

```py
from inspect import signature

# Here `is_set` acts like a flip-flop
is_set = False
params = 0

def curry_partial(func, *partial_args):
    """
    Required argument: func
    Optional argument: partial_args
    Return:
        1) Result of the `func` if
           `partial_args` contains
           required number of items.
        2) Function `wrapper` if `partial_args`
           contains less than the required
           number of items.
    """

    global is_set, params
    
    if not is_set:
        is_set = True
        
        # if func is already a value
        # we should return it
        try: params = len(signature(func).parameters)
        except: return func
    
    try:
        is_set = False
        return func(*partial_args[:params])
    
    except:
        is_set = True
    
        def wrapper(*extra_args):
            """
            Optional argument: extra_args
            Return:
                1) Result of the `func` if `args`
                   contains required number of
                   items.
                2) Result of `curry_partial` if
                   `args` contains less than the
                   required number of items.
            """
            
            args = (partial_args + extra_args)
            
            try:
                is_set = False
                return func(*args[:params])
            except:
                is_set = True
                return curry_partial(func, *args)
    
    return wrapper
```

This indeed isn't very good by design. Instead you should use `class`, to do all the internal works like, for example, the flip-flop (don't worry we don't need any flip-flop there ;-)).

Whenever there's a function that takes arbitrary arguments, you can always instantiate that class passing the function. But this time however, I leave that on you.

Comment: Very elegant solution, however there is one issue. What if func takes a different number of inputs? In the test cases there are also examples of functions taking 2 or 4 inputs. In the feedback in codewars I see the following error:

`<function curry_partial.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f8871cebe18> should equal 3`

This indicates that there will be similar issues as I've had before that using signature to find the number of inputs will fail, as at a certain point it will test wrapper instead of the original func. Any ideas on how to tackle that issue?

Comment: @tobyvd is that dynamic? Or will you be able to know beforehand, how many inputs the function will gonna take?

Comment: Thanks for the update, Ava. Sure enough, it works:) Indeed, once the currying loop is called, the number of input parameters the function requires doesnt change. Now I have a follow-up question. Since I have not programmed with the try-except clause before, I am unfamiliar with its internal logic, so as an exercise I am trying to rewrite your code without those clauses. However I am again encountering issues with the `curry_partial(curry_partial(curry_partial(add, a), b), c)` call. What happens in your code when `curry_partial(add, a)` is executed and the function exits? What is returned?

Comment: Thanks for u̶p̶v̶o̶t̶i̶n̶g̶  accepting my answer @tobyvd . When `curry_partial(add, a)` is first called, it tries to call the `add()` with the argument `a`. If `add()` takes more arguments then it throws an error. That error is handled by the exception block, where it returns the `wrapper()`. If `add()` takes one argument then the result is returned. One more thing, the program will simply fail if the [try-except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) clause is removed. So, instead I would suggest you try rewriting my solution using classes. That will be a good execise.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about *currying*, but if you need a simple partial function generator, you could try something like this:

```
from functools import partial
from inspect import signature

def execute_or_partial(f, *args):
    max = len(signature(f).parameters)
    if len(args) >= max: 
        return f(*args[:max])
    else:
        return partial(f, *args)

s = lambda x, y, z: x + y + z

t = execute_or_partial(s, 1)
u = execute_or_partial(t, 2)
v = execute_or_partial(u, 3)

print(v)

or

print(execute_or_partial(execute_or_partial(execute_or_partial(s, 1), 2), 3))
```

Even if it doesn't solve your original problem, see if you can use the above code to reduce code repetition (I am not sure, but I think there is some code repetition in the inner function?); that will make the subsequent problems easier to solve.

There could be functions in the standard library that already solve this problem. Many pure functional languages like Haskell have this feature built into the language.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to see if incorporating this helps solving the issue.

Comment: this answer inspired me to write a curry decorator

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but maybe this will help someone. This supports keyword arguments, requires no global state, is totally functional, and executes opportunistically (i.e., the first time it has enough arguments). Syntax is extremely neat:

```
@curried
def test(x, y, z=4):
    return x, y, z

# all of these return (1, 2, 3)
test(1)(z=3)(y=2)
test(1)(y=2, z=3)
test(x=1, y=2, z=3)
test(1, 2, 3)

# these return (1, 2, 4)
test(1, 2)
test(1, y=2)
test(y=2)(x=1)
test(y=0)(y=2)(x=1)  # you can override kwargs by giving them again

# this works too
test2 = test(z=3)(1)
test2(21), test2(22)  # returns ((1, 21, 3), (1, 22, 3))
```

Source:

```
from functools import partial
from inspect import signature, _empty

def curried(f):
    def inner(*args, **kwds):
        new_f = partial(f, *args, **kwds)
        params = signature(new_f, follow_wrapped=True).parameters
        if all(params[p].default != _empty for p in params):
            return new_f()
        else:
            return curried(new_f)
    return inner
```